# Controller.js of CRUD vehicles

Tags: javascript, angular.js, crud

I never took an application in a Model-View-Controller architecture and have some difficulties in front-end. The following code works fine, but what can I do to make "layers" of better code and even the application directories?

This is a single file located in `/resources/js/controller.js`.

**Controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/cadastro', {
        controller: 'veiculoController',
        templateUrl: '/tpl-cadastrar.tpl'
    }).when('/', {
        controller: 'indexController',
        templateUrl: '/tpl-index.tpl'
    }).when('/info/:id', {
        controller: 'infoController',
        templateUrl: '/tpl-info.tpl'
    });
});

app.controller('veiculoController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.contatos = [{
        nome: "",
        email: ""
    }];
    $scope.selecionados = [];

    $scope.listaAgencias = ["Exemplo 1", "Exemplo 2", "Exemplo 3"];

    $http.get("/api/agencias")
        .success(function (data) {
            var embedded = data._embedded;
            // $scope.listaAgencias = embedded.agencias;
            //listaAgencias will set here
        }).catch(function (error) {
            alert("Erro ao obter listagem de agencias");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });

    $scope.salvar = function () {
        var jsonObj = {
            nome: $scope.nome,
            tipo: $scope.tipo/*,
             agencias: $scope.selecionados,
             contatos: $scope.contatos*/
        };

        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));

        $http.post("/api/veiculos", jsonObj)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.nome = null;
                $scope.tipo = null;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers) {
                alert("Erro ao salvar dados do veiculo!");
                console.log(status + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data));
            });
    };

    $scope.cancelar = function () {
        window.location.href = "/"
    };

    $scope.novoContato = function () {
        $scope.contatos.push({
            nome: "",
            email: ""
        });
    };

    $scope.excluirContato = function () {
        var ultimoItem = $scope.contatos.length - 1;
        $scope.contatos.splice(ultimoItem);
    };

    $scope.selecionarAgencia = function (agencia) {
        $scope.selecionados.push(agencia);
        var index = $scope.listaAgencias.indexOf(agencia);
        $scope.listaAgencias.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.removerAgencia = function (agencia) {
        $scope.listaAgencias.push(agencia);
        var index = $scope.selecionados.indexOf(agencia);
        $scope.selecionados.splice(index, 1);
    };

});

app.controller('indexController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $http.get("/api/veiculos")
            .then(function (data) {
                var embedded = data.data._embedded;
                $scope.resultado = embedded.veiculos;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                alert("Erro ao obter dados");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    };

    $scope.adicionarNovo = function () {
        window.location.href = "/#/cadastro";
    };

    $scope.excluir = function (resultado, index, url) {
        if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja remover?')) {
            $http.delete(url).then(function (data) {
                resultado.splice(index, 1);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                alert("Erro ao excluir!" + error);
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.visualizar = function (url) {
        url = url.replace("http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/", "");
        window.location.href = "/#/info/" + url;
    };
});

app.controller('infoController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/veiculos/" + $routeParams.id)
        .then(function (data) {
            var json = data.data;
            $scope.veiculoNome = json.nome;
            $scope.veiculoTipo = json.tipo;
            $scope.agencias = ["Exemplo 1", "Exemplo 2", "Exemplo 3"];
            $scope.contatos = json.contatos;
        }).catch(function () {
            window.location.href = '/';
        });

    $scope.removerAgencia = function (agencia) {
        if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja remover?')) {
            var index = $scope.agencias.indexOf(agencia);
            $scope.agencias.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };

}]);

app.controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.salvarInformacoes = function () {
        var jsonObj = {
            nome: $scope.novoVeiculo,
            tipo: $scope.novoTipo
        };
        $http.patch("/api/veiculos/" + $routeParams.id, jsonObj)
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.veiculoNome = $scope.novoVeiculo;
                $scope.veiculoTipo = $scope.novoTipo;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                alert("Erro ao atualizar veículo!" + "\t" + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I think you should go through these links: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542353/angularjs-folder-structure 2. https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

Comment: @AyoolaSolomon I will take a look, thanks! And about the code?

Answer (score 2):

In general, I recommend the John Papa's styleguide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

```
modules
  news/
    news.module.js -> To define your module and dependencies
    news.constants.js -> all constants - can be accessible from .config 
    news.mocks.js -> data to use in TDD

    news.directive.js
    news.directive.spec.js

    news.controller.js
    news.controller.spec.js

    news.factory.js
    news.factory.spec.js
```

Comments on your code:

```
angular
  .module('newsApp.news', []);


angular
  .module('newsApp.news')
  .constants('MYCONS', {});


angular
  .module('newsApp.news')
  .directive('myDirective', MyDirective);

  MyDirective.$inject = ['myFactory'];

  /*@ngInject*/
  function MyDirective(myFactory) { }


angular
  .module('newsApp.news')
  .factory('myFactory', MyFactory);

  MyFactory.$inject = ['myFactory'];

  /*@ngInject*/
  function MyFactory(myFactory) {

    activate();

    return {
      getAll: getAll
    };

    function activate() {
      // trigger something
    }

    function getAll() {
      return {}
    }
  }
```

Note: I've noticed that you create methods for the controller. It's a good practice to move all that to a service factory.